# Windows 7 does not connect to the internet

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a problem connecting to the internet with a windows 7 computer.
It is on a LAN and can communicate with other computers on the network.
It can ping it's default gateway, which is an adsl router.

However when I ping google.com from the computer, it gets the following reply from it's gateway: "Destination net unreachable". This tells me it is indeed trying to use it's default gateway. The same problem occurs with all windows 7 computers on the network.

Networking on the LAN works just fine as the windows 7 computers can print over the network.

A windows XP machine on the network can connect to the internet via the router just fine.

Comment: It would help if you could post the results of "ipconfig /all" on one Win7 and one XP computer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something is causing Windows 7 to use IPv6 rather than IPv4?  Try disabling IPv6 under Network and Connection Center → Manage network connections → Adapter properties

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1. Do you need to connect to the Internet through a proxy?
2. Have you checked on the router if you're getting an IP from your service provider?
3. Is your pc IP on the same subnet as the gateway?
4. Try disabling DHCP and giving your PC a static IP in the same subnet as your router.

If that doesn't work, I'm at a loss but I did find this. It might be of some use to you:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18203-internet-troubleshooting-guide.html
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/102-63-windows-internet-troubleshooting

I hope this helps.

Comment: a) No proxy needed.  b) There is a working internet connection. c) Yes d) I will try that, though I don't see how it'll help. The IP I get via DHCP works on the LAN. Intenet connectivity is the problem  Please note that a win XP computer on the same network connects to the internet just fine.

Comment: Darn. I don't suppose the Network Troubleshooter helped? I saw a post on the MS site mentioning Winsock could be corrupt but all it suggests on fixing it is to click Troubleshoot problems.

Comment: Nah, the network troubleshooter has never solved anything for me.

Comment: try to edit your answers rather than adding new ones, please